# CSS- Changing the width of a search box

Tags: html, css, width, search-box

I'd been trying to change the width of the search box in `name="size"` of my HTML template but can't do it even when I tried `width:`.

html:

```
<form class="form" method = "POST" >

        <h1>Soccer Shoes Finder</h1>
        <div class="line-separator"></div>

            <div class="container-fluid form-inline">

                <input class="form-control" name = "name" type="text" placeholder="Name"/>
                <input class="form-control" name = "size" type="text" placeholder="Size"/>
                <button class="form-control fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></button>
            </div>

</form>
```

css of the element:

```
input[name="size"]{
  width: 50%;
}
```

Here's a codepen for better context:

http://codepen.io/tadm123/pen/ZLVWpd

Comment: what output do you want?

Comment: I would like that "size" search box cut to half of it's width.

Comment: check my answer, you can change the col-md- value to your need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend using this method.

```
<form class="form" method="POST">

  <h1 class="text-center">Soccer Shoes Finder</h1>
  <div class="line-separator"></div>

  <div class="container ">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input class="form-control" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-7">

        <input class="form-control" name="size" type="text" placeholder="Size" /></div>

      <div class="col-md-1">
        <button class="form-control " aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button></div>
    </div>

  </div>

</form>
```

Updated Codepen:
http://codepen.io/hunzaboy/pen/aJJpMK

Comment: You can change the col values per your need to fully control the sizes.

Comment: I see, seems like a much better way.

Answer (score 4):

It's getting overwritten by the bootstrap defaults. Specifically:

```
.form-inline .form-control {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

You need to adjust your selector to fix the cascade:

```
.form-inline input.form-control[name="size"]{
  width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

did you try size attribute?

```
<input type="text" size="15"/>
```

Comment: ya I just tried on your codepen it works, make sure you use size="1" or size="2"

Answer (score 1):

The input elements use by default `display: inline;`, you cannot define a width in elements who using that display, if your change the display to `display: inline-block;` you will can change the width of your element.

```
input[name="size"]{
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block; /* <--- Here the change */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a class-name (defined in HTML) of inputText (name).
Adding these lines will help (clean-way/simple).

```
.inputText{
//...
width:200px;
transition: width .4s ease-in;

}
.inputText:hover, .inputText:focus{
width:400px;
}
```

Comment: Useful tip, but it is not an answer. Instead, you should leave a comment in the question (if you can).

Comment: @Hp93 The poster has no reputation for comment, they are allowed only after 50 reputation.

Comment: @Hp93  
atleast try from your side :)